# Can we create a report or something to count field usage and percentage for standard objects?

Tags: apex, administration, financial-services-cloud

I have a requirement that I have to create a report or excel sheet where User can see that a field is how many time filled on record and also user can se the usage percentage of a field on standard objects. I tried with zoominfo field trip which suggested by salesforce but it does not calculate standard objects of financial service cloud.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

[elements.cloud](https://elements.cloud) does [this](https://support.elements.cloud/en/articles/1730649-impact-analysis-dependency-usage-tab-field-population-and-dependency-data):

> Find the object name in the org model, then open up the "Fields" node in its structure. Then select the field (listed by name) you want to investigate and open up the "Usage" tab in the right panel. You will see a vertical bar chart showing how populated a given field is by each record type it is used on.

Elements is a web app that also needs its managed package installed in the linked org to perform the field population % analysis. They do offer a free trial.

Sounds like Field Trip needs an API version bump.